# Initialize static object graph

Tags: c++, tree, static-members

I want to create a number of objects that hold constant data for an application.

I have got the following code until now:

```
class NodeObject;

class ComplexData
{
    struct datum
    {
        Type type;
        int value;
    };
    vector<datum> data;
    vector<NodeObject*> nodeObjects;

public:
    void addDatum(Type, int) const;
    void addNodeObject(NodeObject*) const;
};

class NodeObject
{
    int id;
    string name;
    ComplexData complexData;

    NodeObject(string);                     // private 

public:
    static const NodeObject NODE_1;
    static const NodeObject NODE_2;
    static const NodeObject NODE_3;
};

const NodeObject NodeObject::NODE_1("Node 1");
const NodeObject NodeObject::NODE_2("Node 2");
const NodeObject NodeObject::NODE_3("Node 3");
```

However I'm not sure, how to put the more complex data into my nodes while keeping the single nodes constant. I think, I could drop the `const` keyword since members are private, but that doesn't really solve the problems. At the moment I use this very ugly aproach - I hope there are better ways to do so:

```
class NodeObject
{
    // stuff like before ...
private:
    static bool initialized;
    static bool initialize();
};

bool NodeObject::initialize() {
    // for example
    NODE_1.complexData.addDatum(someType, 1);
    NODE_3.complexData.addNodeObject(&NODE_1);
}
bool NodeObject::initialized = NodeObject::initialize();
```

Due to the fact that I don't need the `bool` variable afterwards I think it can be eliminated somehow.? Putting everything into the constructor might be possible but that will blow up the code too much.

Do ye have any suggestions?

Comment: If the member variables do **not** change during their lifetime you should keep them `const`.

Comment: Do you speak of the single `NodeObject`s or the members like `id`, `name` and `complexData`?